# ExecutorService, получить значение потока, завершение потока, время выполнения

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть такой код:

```
public class TestPoolThread {

public static void myFunc(ArrayList<Integer> iList) 
{

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

   // pool.shutdown();
   // pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

       for(int a : iList)
        {
          tasks.add(() -> calc(a));  
        }

        List<Future<Object>> invokeAll = pool.invokeAll(tasks);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally {
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}

private static boolean calc(int num)
{
    if(num > 5) return true;

    else return false;

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
  test.add(2);
  test.add(7);
  myFunc(test);

}

}
```

Вопросы собственно следующие: Как отловить возвращаемое значение calc? Т.е вернулся true или false? Как завершить поток который вернул false? И главное, как задать время выполнения потока? Т.е если за 5 секунд не отработал, то завершиться. Нашёл вот такие кусочки кода, в них вроде как и ответ на мои вопросы, но не могу понять где их притулить.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(task);

System.out.println("future done? " + future.isDone());

Integer result = future.get();

System.out.println("future done? " + future.isDone());
System.out.print("result: " + result);
```

Второй пример: По поводу таймаута

```
try {
System.out.println("attempt to shutdown executor");
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
System.err.println("tasks interrupted");
}
finally {
if (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    System.err.println("cancel non-finished tasks");
}
executor.shutdownNow();
System.out.println("shutdown finished");
}
```

И ещё пример по поводу возвращаемого значения.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

List<Callable<String>> callables = Arrays.asList(
    () -> "task1",
    () -> "task2",
    () -> "task3");

 executor.invokeAll(callables)
.stream()
.map(future -> {
    try {
        return future.get();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
})
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: С таймаутом разобрался. Недосмотрел. 
List<Future<Object>> invokeAll = pool.invokeAll(tasks, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: С возвратом значения тоже разобрался. 
List<Future<Object>> invokeAll = pool.invokeAll(tasks, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            for(Future<Object> f : invokeAll)
            {
               Object obj = f.get();
               System.out.println(obj);
            }

Comment: Но вот как убить поток который вернул false?

Comment: `Thread.interrupt()` больше вариантов особо нет в java

Comment: Как Object привести к boolean?  if(obj == false)f.cancel(true); Но вылазит несоответствие типов. Как победить?

Comment: откуда obj  прилетает? весь код покажите

Comment: См. второй комент сверху. Но думаю не будет завершать. Это походу не для этих целей.

Comment: Да, завершать не будет, по причине что вызывается после invokeAll. Они уже и так завершились, завершать нечего. Как же тогда быть?

Comment: ВИжу только один вариант: Если где-то в методе доходит до возврата false, то получать текущий поток и грохать прямо там. Типа такого: Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();thread .stop();

Comment: Подскажите как все таки победить несоответствие типов, и вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: Решил сделать проще. Правильно или нет так делать незнаю, но сделал так: String str = obj.toString();  System.out.println(str); А полученную строку я могу уже сравнивать.

Comment: И вот что интересно: Можно ли отловить момент, что поток был завершен по таймауту?

Comment: @Kamenev_D если объект действительно Boolean, то сработает стандартное приведение типов: `(Boolean) obj`